# PhpStorm cannot save files, permission denied. Docker

Tags: php, docker, permissions, phpstorm

I'm using Docker to work with php projects.

When I try to change a file of a project on my host machine, PhpStorm says

[image]

Could someone please help me to configure the permissions so I could work with the files of my project on my host machine. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

#### docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.1"
services:

    mysql:
      image: mysql:8.0
      container_name: symtest-mysql
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - .:/application
      environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=symfony2
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=123
      ports:
        - "8084:3306"

    webserver:
      image: nginx:alpine
      container_name: symtest-webserver
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
          - .:/application
          - ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      ports:
       - "8082:80"

    php-fpm:
      build: phpdocker/php-fpm
      container_name: symtest-php-fpm
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - .:/application
        - ./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
```

UPD: This problem appeared after I generated a new entity inside the docker using `bin/console` command.

Comment: One solution -> use same user on docker and your local host: https://jtreminio.com/blog/running-docker-containers-as-current-host-user/. 
Workaround -> change permission to file with sudo chmod  outside docker

Comment: @JanGaltowski Great article, thank you.